# Render from Helper yields "Missing Template" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, renderpartial, view-helpers

In my coupons view, I call a method in helpers/coupons_helper.rb, which in turn invokes a partial with the intent of returning it's output.  But I receive a "Missing Template" error.  Here is the relevant code:

```
views/coupons/show.html.erb:
  ...
  <%= form_for(@coupon) do |f| %>
    <% new_include(f) %>
  <% end %>

helpers/coupons_helper.rb:
  def new_include(f)
    new_object = Participation.new
    fields = f.fields_for(:participation, new_object, :child_index => :new_include) do |builder|
      render "_locations_include", :f => builder
    end
  end

views/coupons/_locations_include.html.erb:
  Include: <%= f.select :participant_id, @groups %><br>
```

And the error message is:

```
Missing partial coupons/_locations_include with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :rjs, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/Users/jackrg/Documents/YummiApps/yummi1/app/views"
```

The problem turned out to be the leading "_" in the "render" in "new_include".  Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't prefix the underscore in your `render` call:

```
render "locations_include", :f => builder
```

On a side-note, it's probably a bit superfluous to add an `_include` suffix to the file name, since .erb files beginning with an underscore imply that it's a partial.

Comment: I would agree with you, but I have two partials: one called locations_include and the other called locations_exclude.  I did figure out about 15 minutes after posting (after looking at it for an hour before posting) that I had an extraneous "_", but I don't have enough status to post an answer to my own question until 8 hours have elapsed, so I had to accept the scorn heaped upon me by my peers ;)  Anyway, thanks for the observation.